# Window size does not match what I have in the designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I'm not sure why it seems that every time I work with WPF, things are always much more difficult that WinForms or C/SDK.

In this case, the window looks like this in the designer.

[image]

But here's how it looks at run time.

[image]

And my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="InsiderArticlesManager.AuthorWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InsiderArticlesManager"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Set Author" Height="114" Width="341" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" SourceInitialized="Window_SourceInitialized" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Name="lblPrompt" Content="Select Author:" Margin="5,5,5,0" />
        <ComboBox Name="UserList" DisplayMemberPath="Email" Margin="5,0,5,5"></ComboBox>
        <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Name="btnOk" Content="OK" Width="78" Margin="5,5,0,5" IsDefault="True" Click="Ok_Click" />
            <Button Name="btnCancel" Content="Cancel" Width="78" Margin="5,5,5,5" IsCancel="True" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

I thought the whole point of the designer was so that I could see how the window will look. Since it shows me something different, how do I know what size to set it?

Comment: Looking at the `Height` property with a value of 114, I don't know what you are expecting.  Also, you can't directly compare the outlook in the designer to what you will actually see when you run the program.

Comment: @bolkay: The WinForms and SDK designers all showed me what the window would look like at run time. I really don't understand why that's too much to ask with WPF.

Comment: Okay. I get you. You can also take a look at the zoom factor in the designer to further aid your assessment. It could be that you are at 150% or something.

Comment: @bolkay: Changing the zoom doesn't change the layout or the window size relative to the contents. Zoom behaves exactly as I'd expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to set the `Width` and `Height` on the `StackPanel` and set the `Window`'s `SizeToContent` to `WidthAndHeight`. That way the content is always visible, no matter the size of the window border (assuming you size your `StackPanel` correctly :)):

```
<Window x:Class="InsiderArticlesManager.AuthorWindow"
        ...
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel Height="114" Width="341">
        ...
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In your case the difference between design time and runtime occurs because the XAML designer window has a smaller window border size.

Comment: That gets it closer. I don't understand why any of this is needed.

Comment: @JonathanWood Well, that's how the framework was designed, but with time one gets to know and used to the little things.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a very good design to me, and I've been a developer since 1987.